# How to remove certain letters from a string?

Tags: python-3.x, string

This is my code, it's supposed to create a polynom using inputs in the form of coefficients.

```
x = int(input("Hur många koefficienter innehåller ditt polynom?   "))
arr = []
fin = []


for i in range(x):
    num = int(input("Skriv din första koefficient:   "))
    arr.append(num)

for j in range(len(arr)):
    num = (str(arr[j])+ "x^" + str(len(arr)- j)+  " +")
    
for i in range(len(num)):
    if i == '1':
        num.replace(str(i), "")


if num.endswith("x^1 +"):
    num = num[:-5]
if num.endswith("x^0 +"):
    num = num[:-5]

print(num, end=" ")
```

What I've tried is this:

```
for i in range(len(num)):
if i == '1':
    num.replace(str(i), "")
```

However it doesn't work, this is how I want the output to be:

```
 Input: [1,2,00,0,5]

 Output: "x^4+2x^3+x^2+x+5"
```

And if this is the input:

```
Input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

I want the output to read

```
Output: "x^4+2x^3+3x^2+4x+1"
```

Comment: Why `00` should convert to `x^2` and `0` to `x` ?

Comment: You are correct my bad 00 and 0 should just be removed.